# In Meteor how to copy data from inside function to other templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Template t1 has this JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.t1.onRendered(function() {
    var mytasks = {
      tasks: [
        { text: "This is task 1" },
        { text: "This is task 2" },
        { text: "This is task 3" } ] } } ) ; }
```

Does Meteor offer a global-variable mechanism which allows me copy the
local mytasks variable into a global variable or share it with other
templates in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable without `var` it will be global to the client, the server, or both (depending on where the declaration is made). For example:

**client/lib/globals.js**

```
myTasks = [{text: "This is task 1"}, {...}];
```

**client/templates/t1.js**

```
Template.t1.helpers({
  tasks: myTasks
});
```

Here, `myTasks` is global to the client. Note that I declared the variable in a file inside of a `lib` directory so it would be loaded before files in other client directories.

---

If `myTasks` will always be accessed via a helper, another possibility is to declare a [global helper](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) like this:

```
Template.registerHelper('myTasks', function() {
  return [{text: "This is task 1"}, {...}];
});
```

And then in your templates:

```html
{{#each myTasks}}
  <p>{{text}}</p>
{{/each}}
```